# Domain for parametrization of $z=xy$

Tags: geometry

I have the following surface $z=xy$ and I need to provide a parameterization. I thought about the application I took $(u,v)\in\mathbb R^2$, sends them in $(u,v,uv)$. However, I cannot understand which open set to consider as the domain of this parameterization.

Comment: Take $\Bbb R^2$ itself.

Comment: In case it's useful, if you rotate your coordinate system 45 degrees, there's a parameterization where you send $(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ to $(a+b,a-b,a^2-b^2)$. This makes it clearer that the $(1,1)$-direction and the $(1,-1)$ direction are the "principal axes" of this surface.

Answer (score 0):

Indefinitely many parameterizations possible.

$$ ( x = u+v, y= u-v,z=u^2-v^2) $$

$$ ( x = \frac{u+v}{p}, y = \frac{u-v}{q}, z =\frac { u^2-v^2}{pq}) $$

$$ ( x = \frac {\sin u \cosh v}{a}, y = \frac{\cos u \sinh v}{b}, z =\frac { \sin  2 u \sinh 2 v }{4ab} )$$

$$ \left( x =f(u,v), y= g(u,v),z= f(u,v) g(u,v) \right)$$

Domain of each case is set by using the maxima/minima of chosen functions.

For example in the first simple case if domain of $u$ is $(-1,2)$ and for $v$ $ (-3,-5)$ then z range is unbounded but $(u,v)$ and individual $(u,v)$ domains are $ (-1,-3),(2,-5)$.

Answer (score 0):

$z = xy$ implies $2 z = 2 x y $

In matrix-vector form

$ r^T Q r + b^T r = 0 $

where $Q = \begin{bmatrix}0  && 1 && 0 \\ 1 && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && 0  \end{bmatrix}$ and $ b = [0, 0, -2]^T$

Diagonalize $Q$ it becomes

$Q = R D R^T$

with

$D = \begin{bmatrix} 1&&0&&0\\0 && -1 && 0 \\0 && 0 && 0 \end{bmatrix} $

$R = \begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2} } && -\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} && 0 \\
\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2} } && \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2} } && 0 \\
0 && 0 && 1 \end{bmatrix}$

Define a change of variables $r = R v$, where $v = [v_1, v_2, v_3]^T$, then

$ v^T D v + b^T R v = 0 $

$v_1^2 - v_2^2 - 2 v_3 = 0 $

The parametrization of which is

$v_1 = t \sec s $

$v_2 = t \tan s $

$v_3 = \dfrac{1}{2} t^2$

Therefore a parameterization of the surface $r$ is

$r = R v = [ \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} t (\sec s - \tan s) , \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} t (\sec s + \tan s ), \dfrac{1}{2} t^2 ]^T $